SharePoint 2019 - AD Sync not working

I was able to select our FQDN and AD User accounts group. But it is still not syncing. When I set up the connection it gave me no errors. Containers populated correctly and I selected only the one that contained our User accounts.
When I view Event Viewer I am seeing a bunch of errors:



User Profile Service has stopped. No option Central Admin to start it.

I have found several articles that provide a solution but nothing has worked so far. Currently MS Services show User Profile Service as Running and the account is set to Local System.
I also want to make note that when Get-CacheHost is said AppFabricCachingService is UP. Get-CacheClusterHealth is giving a 4.17 fraction for Healthy status on everything. Not sure if this is related or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


No option Central Admin to start it.

Probably, you are at "Services in Farm" page.
Try to navigate "Services on Server" page - Start option should be there.
You can also start it from SharePoint Management Shell, smth like:
$srv = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? { $_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service" -or $_.Service -eq "UserProfileService" };
$srv | % {Write-Host $_.Server $_.Status; if ($_.Status -ne "Online") {Start-SPServiceInstance $_}; }

Then, got to Monitoring - Check job status - filter by Job Definition:  "User Profile Service Application - User Profile ActiveDirectory Import Job" and make sure that this task is completed successfully.

I ran the script you provided.
Status on Management Shell said it was Provisioning
I went to Services on Server page as you mentioned and that status there now Started, but Compliant says No (Fix) and now I see the option to Stop. (Side note:
If I click Fix, it just stops the service again.)
I also went to Monitor - Check job status and it does show that jobs as Succeeded. However, I am still showing 5 users, all of which I manually added to Sharepoint. Is it possible that it just won't show more than that until I share the new URL to the new Sharepoint to other users?

Status of User Profile Service should be Online and Compliant on all servers with Frontend\Application\SingleServer MinRoles. Which MinRole does your server has?

Also, the best option would be to look at the ULS logs, you can filter it by rows containing UserProfileADImportJob or Category: UserProfiles, then it will become clear how the synchronization went.
And - No, SharePoint User Profile Sync does not depend of what sites you shared with what users. It should sync all users from OU you've specified. But previously there was a bug that SP did not synchronize users if they were selected directly by checkboxes in Sync Connection settings. It is better to select only OU.

I ran this script "Get-SPServer | Select-Object Name, Role" and got this - Name: DOMAINNAME | Role: SingleServerFarm, Name: exchrelay.domain.com (Exchange Relay) | Role: Invalid.
I found the ULS log for UserProfileADImportJob. Everyone entry is the same thing: [User Profile Service Application_UserProfileADImportJob]: Profile Application [Id=eab58352-89de-4fbb-a027-9ca247ca7fbf,Status=Provisioning] is not online. Job run aborted.
